# Hubspot external embed code NOT working with OptinMonster. Looking for code review

Tags: html, hubspot

Hubspot's external embed code is supposed to be copy/paste and BAM - you're good. I can't get the code to work in OptinMonster's ad builder. The email form I am trying to add does not appear. (New to this so there is likely something I'm missing.)

```
<html>

<img src="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
    hbspt.forms.create({ 
        portalId: '2786381',
        formId: 'fdaf93fb-5e42-46bd-84fc-57156ce26d07'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a Javascript code that runs asynchronously to create the hubspot form. What optin softwares such as Optinmonster and [MailOptin](https://mailoptin.io/) accept are custom HTML form code not JavaScript codes.